# How detect if text fix?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I want it to look like this ：

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

(I can't show images)

When I open the code with UITextView can be scrolled, I can scroll it to change the keys to the detection line. Then it detects the words successfully and changes the background.

I am new making iBeacons.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Image(imageNum: 10000)
    locationManger.delegate = self
    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse) {
        locationManger.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    locationManger.startRangingBeacons(in: region)
    showBlshText()
    departmentMessage.isScrollEnabled = true
    departmentMessage.isPagingEnabled = true
    departmentMessage.isEditable = false
    departmentMessage.isSelectable = true
    departmentMessage.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.link 
}
```

Comment: Can you please frame the question correctly, so that we can help you out.

Comment: Check the `departmentMessage.text` or `departmentMessage.attributedText` (it's unclear if you can have multiple colors), check it, add colors if needed to the text and to the background.